# TestDisk always return corrupted files

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery, testdisk

I accidentally remove all of my files (**Python** Files) in Visual Studio Code, and I tried to use `testdisk` tool to recover them, I checked what filesystem I'm using, and it is `/dev/sda5` and the type is `ext4`

**This is the steps I did to recover my files:**

`$ sudo testdisk /dev/sda5`

I selected `None` as the partitioned media. And then, I didn't see the `undelete` option, so I chose the `List` option.
And finally I moved to the path that my files got deleted, and I copy them all to my desktop, but when I open a file, no matter which file, the data is just random bytes. The data in the file is corrupted.

If I did something wrong, please guide me step by step how to do that, I had a lot of important projects ):

---

**I am using Ubuntu**

Comment: If you've deleted the files and they can't be recovered, they're gone. Unfortunately it doesn't help you right now but this is why people take regular backups.

Comment: @roaima But there are tools to recover delete files, such as `testdisk`, no ?

Comment: It looks like you tried to restore the files to the same device from which you were recovering them. The recovered files will have overwritten the remains you were recovering, probably at the same time, so you've totally destroyed any chance whatsoever of getting anything useful back. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

**I fear it is already too late by now.**

If you keep using the device, or possibly even if you just keep it mounted. It is almost guaranteed that all deleted files **will** eventually become overwritten and thus practically impossible to recover.

What you should have done

1. Immediately *umount* the device.
2. Make a complete sector-by-sector image clone of the device.
3. Do recovery-work on copies of the image only.
4. Do not mount the device until you got the files back from your image-file.

Also. What kind of physical storage device used will affect procedures and chance of success.

Comment: When I try to `umount` the filesystem it says `umount: /: target is busy` (`/dev/sda5`)

Comment: I doubt it. unless it is a hard drive and not an ssd AND you have kept the device un-mounted since you deleted the files.

Comment: That probably means your computer has been reading and writing to that block-device since the files were deleted... They are almost certainly gone...